# what's the performance impact causing from the large size of Apache's access.log?

Tags: server, apache2

I am using Apache. Sometimes it stops working and I have to manually restart it. Why does this happen?

What's the performance impact on my application causing from the large size of Apache's `access.log`?

Answer (score 0):

> I am using Apache. Sometimes it stops working and I have to manually restart it. Why does this happen?

Impossible to answer. But ... check your logs (not just the apache.log). A crash is always logged. Probably `/var/log/syslog`.

> What's the performance impact on my application causing from the large size of Apache's access.log?

Depends on what you call large and what size of memory you have in that machine (and some other things). 1Tb would probably kill anyones performance but 25Mb or so is not large (though still more than a log file has to be in size).

2 things:

- if the log file is large FIX THE PROBLEM that is causing it to increase. The problem will be stated in the apache log.
- Please install and use ["logrotate"](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html). That will let your compress log files at a certain size making them small. I thought that would be installed already though.

Comment: I disagree that a large access.log file indicates any problem, but rather it just means the web site is very busy with many accesses. I also disagree that a large access.log file has any effect on performance or that it is a function of memory in the machine. Currently, I am running a forever wget loop against my most pathetic server (I use it for minimum requirements testing), with only 128 MBytes of memory. The access.log file is now up to 110 Megabytes, and I haven't noticed a degradation in performance. I'll analyze it in better detail later, and report back.

Comment: However, there does appear to be a very slow memory leak, and gradually I am observing more and more swap space being used, which might eventually become an issue. The server is 14.04.

Comment: I fetched 3.1 million web pages from my server. The rate both started and ended at about 8,800 pages per minute, and the access.log file ended up being 347 megabytes.

Comment: I do agree with @Doug Smythies that large access.log file should be normally considered as a problem or affect performance, check your application for memory leaks, sometime the issue is with database server, setup monitoring, does this happen at a particular time, or is this random? Even if logrotate is installed you may need to configure it.

Comment: @Doug Smythies 347MB is neligible size. If you told me it was 1TB and there were no impact in performance then I would be surprised.